# Add labels to panel including 3 plots and a legend

Tags: r, label

I would like to create a figure that has 3 plots (p1, p2, p3) labeled with "(A)", "(B)", "(C)" and a legend with no label. But my trials have been unsuccessful. Would you mind helping me? Thanks for your time!

I extracted the legend from one of my plots thanks to the function get_legend

```
get_legend<-function(myggplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(myggplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)
}
legend <- get_legend(p1)# Save the legend
p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.position="none")#  Remove the legend from the box plot
```

This is the script I wrote to have the final figure, however, it does not work:

```
grid.arrange(p3, p1, p2, legend, labels=c("(A)", "(B)", "(C)", " "), ncol=4, widths=c(2, 2, 2, 0.8))
```

This script below works but unfortunately does not label my 3 plots:

```
grid.arrange(p3, p1, p2, legend, ncol=4, widths=c(2, 2, 2, 0.8))
```

[image: 3plots without labels and legend]

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code (untested):

```
plots <- mapply(arrangeGrob, list(p3, p1, p2, legend), bottom=c("A", "B", "C", ""), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```